# Bootstrap. Как сделать карусель на всю высоту экрана?

Tags: css, bootstrap, карусель

Как сделать [слайдер](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) на весь экран?

Пробовал через стили:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id ="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=Main" class="img-responsive" alt="Main">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Main slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Second" class="img-responsive" alt="Second">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=Third" class="img-responsive" alt="Third">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Но якобы слайдер становится по всему экрану (но картинка слайдера как была так и осталась на месте, т.е. не по всему экрану + навигационные спаны упрыгали вниз и их не видно). Может дело в размере, но я менял до 3081х1733, всё равно стоит на месте.

Answer (score 3):

Надо ещё самим картинкам задать 100% по ширине и высоте. Т.е., для `.carousel-inner img` тоже их прописать.

И после этого класс `img-responsive` уже не нужен.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-inner img {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id ="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=Main" alt="Main">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Main slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Second" alt="Second">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=Third" alt="Third">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slider</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide ="prev">
    <span class ="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide ="next">
    <span class ="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```